# Python and C++ communication stdout and stdin

Tags: python, c++, stdout, communication, stdin

I have to pass array from  Python to  C++  and back using  stdout and stdin.  I  can pass it to C++ . However I cant send it back to python.  I think I don't understand how to set stdout mode. Please give me advice. Thank you.
My  Python code:

```
import struct
import subprocess
#import msvcrt
#import os
import random

array = [1.0 for _ in range(10)]
proc = subprocess.Popen(['test.exe'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
for item in array:
proc.communicate(struct.pack('<f', item))

data = bytes()
while len(data) < len(array)*4:
data = data + proc.communicate()[0]

print (len(data))

#print('Python:')
#msvcrt.setmode (proc.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
proc.stdin.close()
proc.stdout.close()

proc.wait()
```

MY C++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
int result;

// Set "stdin" to have binary mode:
result = _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
if (result == -1)
perror("Cannot set mode");
else
fprintf(stderr, "'stdin' successfully changed to binary mode\n");

// Set "stdout" to have binary mode:
result = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
if (result == -1)
perror("Cannot set mode");
else

fprintf(stderr, "'stdout' successfully changed to binary mode\n");

int i = 0;
while (!std::cin.eof())
{
float value;
std::cin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
if (std::cin.gcount() > 0)
{
std::cerr << "Car " << i << ": " << value << std::endl;
i++;
}
if (std::cin.gcount() > 0)
{
std::cerr << "Car " << i << ": " << value << std::endl;
std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
i++;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work properly? What do you expect it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: It seems that you never even attempt to read from stdout in your python code. Did you expect something different?

Comment: Sorry for mistake,  have edited my code. it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

communicate() is a one-time method that creates background threads to read stdout/err until they are closed, pumps data to stdin and waits for program completion. The way you are doing it, the first communicate() doesn't return until the C++ program terminates and nothing after that yields any results.

As long as input and output aren't too big, you can still use communicate() by building stdin before use and processing stdout when done:

```
import struct
import subprocess
from cStringIO import StringIO

stdin_buf = StringIO()
array = [1.0 for _ in range(10)]
for item in array:
    stdin_buf.write(struct.pack('<f', item))

proc = subprocess.Popen(['test.exe'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate(stdin_buf.getvalue())

# assuming the result comes back the same way it went in...
item_len = struct.calcsize('<f')
stdout_buf = StringIO(out)
stdout_buf.seek(0)
for i in range(len(out)/item_len):
    val = struct.unpack('<f', stdout_buf.read(4))
```

If you have a lot of data or want to be more pipeline-y, you can create your own threads to pump data into stdin and process the results on stdout.